# Pass function pointer to xTaskCreate with void* pvParameters

Tags: c++, pointers, task, freertos

Is it possible to pass a function pointer as the parameter for the freeRTOS xTaskCreate function? 
I suspect I need to cast the void* pvParameters within the task before I can call it but I am not sure what such as cast would be.

```
class param
{
    private:
        //Initialized during construction to hardware specific value. 
        uint8_t mParam = 0;
    public:
        uint_8 getParam() {return mParam;}
};

void task(void* pvParameters)
{
    //get hardware specific pvParameters.
    uint8_t hwParam = pvParameters(); 
    // Do task things. 
}

main()
{
    param p;
    uint32_t result; 
    result = xTaskCreate(task, "Task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, (void *)&p.getParam, configMAX_PRIORITIES - 1, nullptr); //lint !e712 implicit conversion from long to int
    if (result == 0)
    {
        //print error msg.
    }
    else
    {
        vTaskStartScheduler();
        for(;;) {ASM("NOP");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using &p (address of object p) as argument to access the complete param object using a cast like this:

```
param& p = *(param*)pvParameters;
```

Beware that for a number of ports/MCUs the main stack is reused as ISR stack and main stack allocated arguments might get corrupted. Better use e.g. static/new param object.